Splicing 3 wires into 4 wires 220 to an RV pad
I already have, not connected to anything, a buried conduit with 3 wires (2 black, and a large silver bare wire) going to an rv pad. I already have an RV subpanel which is designed to accept 2 hot 220 wires from which one leg goes to a 110 30 amp rv plug and the other leg goes to a 110 20 amp GFI plug. I want to disconnect a 4 wire 220 cable from an oven which is attached at the other end to a 40 amp double pole breaker at the main panel and reroute it to slice onto to the above described 3 wires in a metal box. I tried connecting the 2 black wires of the 3 to the red and black, and connecting the large silver bare wire to the white neutral wire and attaching the ground wire to the metal splice box. Then at the other end the 2 black wires went to the power, the large silver wire to the neutral bar and then grounding the panel box to an 8ft grounding rod. The 20 amp GFI plug trips with just a power saw and I didn't even try the 30amp plug. How should have wired this?

"at the other end the 2 black wires went to the power, the large silver wire to the neutral bar and then grounding the panel box to an 8ft grounding rod. The 20 amp GFI plug trips with just a power saw" Technically, though not up to NEC, this wiring should have worked. Check the GFI wiring: using only the Line screws and not the Load screws, power from breaker to narrow side of outlet slot, neutral to wide slot. GFI neutral wire to neutral bar, not ground bar. Is the GFI outlet old? Does the saw work on GFCI's elsewhere?

Connecting the neutral to neutral and the ground to nothing but a ground rod is both clever and a code violation.  What you have done there is "invented" the Japanese "TT" grounding system*.  That ONLY works because everything in a Japanese home is protected by GFCI.  It's not Code here, but also, the 30A socket is not protected by GFCI.  If you insist on doing it this way, you need to obtain a GFCI breaker for that. 30A GFCI sockets don't exist and finding a single-pole 30A GFCI breaker may be a challenge.  You can always use a 30A 2-pole breaker and just not use the 2nd hot/live terminal.
Also, mail order has "broken" product liability. Companies like Amazon are using "3rd party sellers" to evade legal responsibility for their products, and deliberately selling dangerous junk which is not UL listed (as it must be per Code NEC 110.2).  That sadly includes HomeDepot.com and Lowes.com "Ship To Store". You can spot these cheap/dangerous RV boxes first by the price but second because they have obvious Chinese circuit breakers.  It will be impossible to get a GFCI breaker for one of these (or any parts or support at all).  Such panels need to be returned with a vengeance!
I for one really like the ABB/General Electric RV park panels because they provide a spare 3rd or 5th spare breaker space, just what you need to fit a 30-amp 2-pole GFCI in there.

A large silver bare wire?  That sounds an awful lot like SEU cable.  Regardless, it is an aluminum bare ground wire, and that is not allowed underground (becuase it will corrode - you can't keep water out of conduit).
So regardless it sounds like all 3 wires need to come out since they are the wrong type for the job.  Now 4 wires can be installed in place.  If the wires are entirely in conduit, use THHN or XHHW.  Aluminum at #6 or larger is fine if the ground is insulated, but it is all the more important to torque screws with a torque screwdriver.
If the wires are 6 AWG or smaller, the wires must be native colors - green for ground, white or gray for neutral, and the 2 live wires can be any other colors (both the same is fine e.g. black-black).
Since the wire is the wrong type, it must definitely be replaced with 4-wire and we avoid the topic of whether it would have been legal to continue using it due to grandfathering.

Now let's talk about fitting the new wires into the existing conduit.  Since your existing wires are aluminum, you can always downsize 1 wire size and use copper for the same amps.  However you probably won't need to do that.  The smallest aluminum wire commonly seen is big enough that you won't have any trouble fitting the correct aluminum or copper wire.

If you will ONLY ever power the 20A and 30A sockets, then #10 copper or #8 aluminum will suffice.  However the circuit breaker must be changed to 30A.

If you ever hope to power a 240V / 14-50 outlet, then you will need #8 copper or (surprise) #8 aluminum for a 40A breaker.

If you want to run the 14-50 socket at 50 amp, and the existing range wiring is big enough for that, then you would need #8 copper which is not NM or UF, or #6 aluminum.


* I just saw that video yesterday, so it was meant to find you! LOL

First of all, in most places it has been 120 and 240 instead of 110 and 220 for decades. Some places it is even up to 125 and 250. That doesn't change the work involved but gives an indication of age, along with the "silver wire".
What you have is two hots and a neutral. In ye olden times, ground wires were not required and, in certain situations, a bare neutral was allowed. However, any new 240V subpanel must have 4 wires in order to support any 120V circuits:

Hot 1 - Typically black (but any color except green, green/yellow, white, gray or bare/uninsulated is OK)
Hot 2 - Typically black or red (but same rules as Hot 1)
Neutral - White or gray
Ground - Green, green/yellow or bare/uninsulated

Which means that you have two choices:

Replace the old neutral wire with a new white wire and add a green or bare ground wire
Designate the old neutral wire as ground and add a new white neutral wire

The key is buried conduit. With buried cable you are stuck - you can't turn a 3-wire cable into a 4-wire cable. But you can add another wire to conduit. With a couple of things to keep in mind:

Wire size: Use an ampacity chart such as this one from cerrowire to determine what size wires you need. At typical subpanel sizes, the two hots and the neutral have the same requirement, which happens to be 8 AWG copper or aluminum for 40A. With larger sizes there is a difference between copper and aluminum - e.g., 50A requires 8 AWG copper or 6 AWG aluminum. You can always use larger wire. But check the wire currently in the conduit to determine whether it is even suitable for 40A. Ground wires can generally be smaller - 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum is good for up to 60A.
Conduit fill: Use a conduit fill calculator such as this one from Southwire to figure out what size wires you can legally run through the conduit. If the existing conduit isn't large enough for the necessary wires then you either need new conduit or rethink the project.


One possibility, if the conduit has to be replaced because of the conduit fill rules: Find a used transformer that can take 240 on the primary and give 120/240 center tapped on the secondary at 40 amps (10kVA) or more. The existing conduit wiring, being 240 only if used as 2 powers & ground, can feed the transformer. Then feed the RV panel from the transformer as if it was a utility-driven panel, with neutral & ground bonded in the panel and the required ground rods. Cost of transformer vs cost & work of replacing the conduit would be considered.

Thanks all, I'm off for Christmas tomorrow but when I get back I'll yank out the 3 wires if I can (encased and in a 1" conduit with I'm sure a 90 or 2) and replace it with the proper 4 separate wires and panel.

Do yourself a favor and securely attach new wires to old so that you can pull them through the conduit more easily. Or attach a pull string to the old as you pull it old and use the pull string to pull new. What you don't want to do is pull out the old and then try to figure out how to fish the new wires through, because if there are any complications (turns, debris, etc.) it will be hard to do.

You need to draw in another wire - the neutral.  You currently have only two hots and a ground.  Which is fine if you only want 220V, and no use if you want 110V.
Bootlegging it to use the ground as a neutral is dangerous, and will trip GFCIs.

Older circuits used a bare neutral sometimes with no ground.

I'm a novice at this but now I'm thinking why do I even need to run 220v if I am only using 110v. It is about 50 ft of 4 wire to my splice and then may another 120 ft to the rv pad with the 3 wire. Why not put in a 30 amp single pole beaker at the main panel and run 110 all the way with 3 wires or if needed run the 220v the 50 ft on 4 wire and convert it there to 110 and then use my 3 wires as a hot, neutral and ground. All of the wires are 6 or larger.At the rv end then couldn't I just split the 110 hot wire to the 30 amp breaker and the 20 amp breaker?
